# How does this time complexity reduce?

Tags: time-complexity, big-o

Suppose I have two factors, N and M, and a constraint that M <= N, and I have an operation with O(log(N)) time complexity, that needs to be run M times, however, N reduces by 1 on each iteration, so it looks roughly like this:

```
O(log(N) + log(N - 1) + ... + log(N - (M - 2)) + log(N - (M - 1)))
```

How do I reduce this to a simple expression?

as a bonus, I kind of simplified things above, N doesn't definitely reduce by 1 on each iteration, this only occurs in the worst case (where M = N), it actually reduces by the result of the prior log(N) operation, which is some series of M numbers, lets call it series R, and series R sums to N, so it's really like:

```
O(log(N) + log(N - R(0)) + log(N - R(0) - R(1)) + ... + log(N - R(0) - R(1) - ... - R(M - 2)) + log(N - R(0) - R(1) - ... - R(M - 2) - R(M - 1)))
```

where it's a summation with sub summations... is this able to be simplified?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since `log(a) + log(b) = log(a*b)` it follows that your equation equals:

```
O( log( N*(N-1)*(N-2)* ... * (N-(M-1)) * (N-M) ) )
```

So for the worst case scenario `M=N-1` gives the upper bound `O(log(N!))`

In the general case the complexity is `O(log(N!/(N-M)!))`. Which increases with M as expected.

Comment: I'm slightly confused. In my reading of this, as M increases, the time complexity improves, but that shouldn't be the case? since the closer M gets to N (increases), it should be getting worse.  Am I reading this wrong here? or are M and N reversed?

Comment: There seems to be an error in the complexity for the general case, it actually is `O(log(N!/(N-M)!))` which increases with M, just as expected.